# Sql Server Date Language within Function

Tags: sql-server, datetime, internationalization, scope

There's some code originally written for Oracle which has been converted to use SQL Server.
However, there's currently an issue in France, where the date names are displayed in English.
This is because CONVERT is being used to change the format, but `SET LANGUAGE` is not used to alter the session's language (whilst in Oracle language is included as part of the `to_char` function which provides equivalent conversion).

Looking deeper I believe `SET LANGUAGE` wasn't used because the code's in a function - and because `set` has side effects it cannot be included there.

Does anyone know of a way around this; i.e. to change the language for a single statement within a function, rather than affecting the entire session?

**EDIT**

To better illustrate my issue, imagine trying to recreate the Oracle functionality in SQL - e.g. as below.

```
--this won't work because SET LANGUAGE affects the state of the session; 
create function dbo.to_char(@date datetime, @format nvarchar(32), @language nvarchar(32))
returns nvarchar(32)
as 
begin
      declare @result nvarchar(32)
      , @formatSql int

      --here we need to map the available Oracle options to their SQL equivs
      --SQL is more restrictive in that it uses predefined date formats rather than masks
      --I can't recall the typical valid oracle format masks - but just append to this those that you use
      set @formatSql = 
      case @format
            when 'dd mon yyyy' then 106
            when 'mon dd yyyy' then 107
            when 'dd/mm/yyyy'  then 103
            when 'mm/dd/yyyy'  then 101
            else 121 --default to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)
      end

      select @language = REPLACE(@language,'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE','')
      , @language = REPLACE(@language,'=','')
      , @language = REPLACE(@language,' ','')

      set language @language 

      set @result = CONVERT(nvarchar(32), @date, @formatSql)

      set language English --revert session language

      return @result
end
go


select dbo.to_char(getutcdate(), 'dd mon yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAG = French') --from dual ;)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want the months (or maybe weekdays) of the date in French ? If you only want the mm/dd/yyyy format, you can use convert(nvarchar(10), date, 103).

Comment: Hey @SemVanmeenen; sadly not - I want language - e.g. `14-FÉV-2013` vs `14-FEB-2013`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work in a function and will give you a table with the number and the abbreviation in uppercase French for each month. You can then use it to build your formatted date.

```
Declare @months varchar(200)

select @months = shortmonths
from sys.syslanguages
where lcid = 1036 --i.e. French

Declare @individual varchar(20) = null
declare @monthsTable table (monthNumber int identity(1,1), name nvarchar(20))

WHILE LEN(@months) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%,%',@months) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@months, 0, PATINDEX('%,%',@months))
        SET @months = SUBSTRING(@months, LEN(@individual + ',') + 1, LEN(@months))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @months
        set @months = null
    END
    insert into @monthsTable(name) select UPPER(@individual) 
END
```

Out of curiosity, is there a reason you aren't doing this in the frontend ? Sql isn't really suited for formatting tasks.

Comment: Thanks @SemVanmeenen.  We're using an off the shelf product where the only customisations allowed are to the database.  I suspect the `set language` option will work (I've not seen the code - all customisations are handled by an off shore team; I just heard their problem and suggested set language, then thought perhaps their issue was due to the scope issue mentioned above as otherwise Google/SO would have resolved their issues before news of their problem made it to me).  Thought I'd investigate the alternate option whilst waiting for more info from them.